# Null in ANGULAR html template

Tags: angular

I get the following error in my input ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'null'.

this line that is causing the error.

```
<input [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': generalConfigurationForm.controls['buisnessName'].errors?.required }" class="form-control valid" id="buisnessName" formControlName="buisnessName" name="buisnessName" required="required" type="text" [(ngModel)]="generalConfiguration.buisnessName" />
```

What should I do when this line is null? I would like the result for 'is-invalid' to be false.

```
generalConfigurationForm.controls['buisnessName'].errors?.required
```

Comment: You could just use a ternary there so: `[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': generalConfigurationForm.controls['buisnessName'].errors?.required ? true : false }"`

Comment: #oHello this cause the error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true' when the field is not required.

Comment: In that case you will need to set the value when the template is initialised in some variable in the controller to be false, otherwise it will be null and then changed after the view initialises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ngModel with reactive form control. Remove ngModel and set form control value.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated